# Select an li item and then enable a input button

Tags: jquery

I have created a list which when I select highlights but I only want one item at time to highlight - also as the item is highlighted I need to enable the button - example below:

```
 $('#sn-list li a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('highlight');


        if (!currentPage.parent().hasClass('highlight')) {
            $('#tabulation_button').removeProp("disabled");
            alert('hello');
        }
        else {
            $('#tabulation_button').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/rEH5L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$(this).parent('li').toggleClass('highlight');
```

with

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
```

Secondly I don't see where this variable is  declared `currentPage`

This makes no sense in the current context as these are not defined in the code that you have mentioned..

```
if (!currentPage.parent().hasClass('highlight')) {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEH5L/1/)**